# How can I use IIS and Wamp on the same computer at the same time?

Tags: apache, iis, wamp, port

I am developing ASP.NET projects and PHP projects and I wonder how could I resolve that both IIS and WAMP would run at the very same time from the very same computer. They are in conflict, probably due to port number and now I need to stop one to be able to start the other, but how should I change my settings to make sure that both are running? Is it possible to enable them on the same port, possibly with some system which would decide based on the structure of the request whether Apache or IIS should handle it? Can I write some code somehow which would preprocess the requests and decide whether they should be sent to Apache or IIS? If so, how?